# Capybara + Rspec + Selenium: Page always blank in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, integration-testing, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm trying to write integration tests with Capybara, but every time the Selenium-controlled browser pops up, the page is blank.  Furthermore, for a simple assertion like `page.should have_selector('title')`, I get errors like

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title')
   expected following output to contain a <title/> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
   </html>
```

I.e., the page is empty.

I'm visiting a path that's valid.  If I do a `save_and_open_page`, the page **is** there.

The relevant part of the Gemfile is

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.4'
  gem 'nokogiri'
  gem 'webrat'

  # capybara for javascript testing
  gem 'capybara'

  # launchy allows us to do save_and_launch_page, which is very helpful during testing
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

The app is using Rails 3.1.1.  I've done `bundle install` and added

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

to my `spec_helper`.

Note, these are *integration* tests, not controller tests - I'm not missing `render_views`.

I have other apps where this stuff works fine, which makes me think I'm either missing something in my config or there is an issue with the specific versions being used.

Selenium is trying to use Firefox, and I'm on OS X Snow Leopard, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try removing webrat from your gemfile. I believe both webrat and capybara try to run the tests in the requests directory.

Comment: Odd.  I have another project that happily uses both.  Different versions, I guess.  Thanks!